# Is there a proof that there is no sequence for root 2 like there is for the golden ratio?

Tags: irrational-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

The golden ratio has can be approximated as a ratio of 2 successive terms of the Fibonacci sequence.  1 1 2 3 5 8 etc... The rule is pretty simple. Is there a proof that there are no rules where you can generate the square root of 2?

I looked at the Pell equation, but you can't get a rule out of it, is there anything else or is the Golden Ratio special? For example I tried picking random numbers to start with and then if you keep doing the same rule eventually you get the golden ratio again if you do the ratio between successive terms!

Comment: As stated, this question is unclear. What do you mean by a 'rule' specifically in this context?

Comment: The reason for this is that the Fibonacci Sequence (the general form for any starting values) is highly dependent on the golden ratio, and even has a closed form in terms of the golden ratio. My understanding is that the OP desires a sequence for which $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \sqrt{2}$. OP, feel free to correct me if I am wrong. The only ambiguity is that mentioned by Stefan above... what is a "rule" in this case?

Comment: OP probably desires a sequence of integers for which the above limit holds. Certainly one exists, but whether it is defined by a nice closed formula, I don't know.

Comment: To emphasize the relevance of my previous comment: Consider $a_{n} = \sqrt{2}^{n}$.

Comment: @Stefan to make it much more clearer: $a_n=\sqrt{2}$, which wouldn't solve anything OP meant.

Comment: @kccu $b_n = \lfloor \sqrt{2}^{n} \rfloor$ should work, right?

Comment: @Stefan Ah, I guess I meant a recurrence relation (like the Fibonacci sequence) rather than a closed form.

Comment: I was saying like how fibonacci sequence you just keep adding the previous number then when you get far enough you divide the 2 biggest ones you have and you got an approximation. Is there a way to do it with 2^.5 or instead a proof that you can't.

Answer (score 3):

The series you mentioned for the golden ratio is actually the series of convergents of its continued fraction. 
$$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\dotsb}}$$

Every number has a continued fraction, but numbers which are the solution to a second degree equation with rational coefficients (quadratic irrationals) have periodic ones.

$$\sqrt{2}=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\dotsb}}}$$

You can prove this equality by noticing that

$$x=1+\frac{1}{1+\color{red}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\dotsb}}}}=1+\frac{1}{1+x}$$

So if you stop this sequence at the first points you get increasingly good approximations.

Comment: but like how fibonacci sequence goes 112358 what is the sequence for 2^.5?

Answer (score 1):

As people say in the comments, you need to define what sort of rules are allowed.  The classic [Babylonian sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) $a_1=1, a_n=\frac 12(a_{n-1}+\frac 2{a_{n-1}})$ converges rapidly to $\sqrt 2$.  If you want a [homogeneous linear recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) you need the characteristic polynomial to have a root of $\sqrt 2$ and all other roots smaller than $\sqrt 2$ in absolute value.  You can't do that with integer coefficients, but you can have the characteristic polynomial $(x-\sqrt 2)(x+\sqrt 2-1)=x^2+x-2-\sqrt 2$ so the recurrence would be $x_n=x_{n-1}+(2+\sqrt 2)x_{n-2}$

Comment: i cringe a little inside on the last one. how does it help to find value z via a recursive function that uses z? (no offence)